# BeautifulSoup doesn't find tr tag with style

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I am trying to get the following done:
Open a webpage and get the tr tag with bold font and then filter the links

This works great:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = urllib2.urlopen("https://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Weekly_activities")
data = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
weekliesunsorted = soup.findAll('tr', style="font-weight: bold;")
pvebonus = weekliesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[0]
#and so on...
```

But unfortunately this code doesn't, the fluxunsorted variable is empty, but the tr row does exist

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("https://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Flux")
data = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
fluxunsorted = soup.findAll('tr', style="font-weight:bold;") #empty?
flux = fluxunsorted[0].findAll('a')[0]
```

That's why I am getting the index out of range error.

Why is the list empty?

Comment: Your second code block says `esponse = urllib2.urlopen`, is that just a typo?

Comment: There are no `tr` tags with the style you've selected in the page source of the second link. But, there's one `tr` tag with `<tr style="font-weight:bold">`. Note that there's no space between `weight:` and `bold`.

Comment: was a typo in the code here, i did'nt write that in my code. Even changing the font-weight without a space doesnt work